# Get list of endpoints available at a external API url

Tags: c#, rest, api, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

I've been doing loads of research on this and not much is coming up for me. I'd like to know if it is possible to programmatically connect to a external (not mine) restful API url and somehow get all possible routes this API provides.

For example i have access to https://www.someapiservice.com/someapi/. This API has the following routes:

https://www.someapiservice.com/someapi/**someroute/somesubroute**
https://www.someapiservice.com/someapi/**anotherroute/anothersubroute**

Is there some way to programmatically get a list that would contain:

- **someroute/somesubroute**
- **anotherroute/anothersubroute**

Essentially scraping the API for endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, **no**... sort of...

What you are requesting is that all API implementations in the world, or at least on some site *cooperate* with your crawler and give you what you need.

Unless you

- have control on both sides, and can thus provide to the client some discovery mechanism
- know in advance what the other side provides as a discovery mechanism
- can rely on an API registry (directory) of some kind
- or know of some kind of convention for APIs on the target site

then you're out of luck.

Incidentally, one of those discovery mechanisms could be [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle)'s Swagger UI, which is used to document APIs (based on the tags to your question). Perhaps you could leverage that in some way if your third-party site provides it.

Comment: Great, thanks for your time. I had a feeling this was the answer. I'll just have to revert to manually recording the endpoint via their APi reference documentation. This saves me spinning my wheels on this one. Much appreciated!